# What is the purpose of RoundhousE's RestoreRun mode?

Tags: data-migration, roundhouse

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse/wiki/RoundhousEModes), RoundhousE has 3 modes:

- Normal
- DropCreate
- RestoreRun

The first 2 are clear, but I don't understand [RestoreRun Mode](https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse/wiki/RoundhousEModes) and the benefit it offers in Production:

> **Once you have gone to production, you switch from DropCreate to
>   RestoreRun mode if your database is small enough**. If not, you can
>   continue with the idea of maintenance mode by switching to a new script
>   name that you are making changes to. You can also backup the structure
>   only (and some of the lookup data if you use a tool like LiteSpeed)
>   and restore from that.

I was under the impression that RestoreRun would restore a backup of the database before running the migrations scripts. If this is the case, I could see it being useful in development where I am repeatedly testing my new scripts, but don't see the purpose of it for production.

Here are my questions:

1. Am I misunderstanding the purpose of RestoreRun?
2. What is an example scenario of how RestoreRun would benefit a production deployment?
3. Are there any other differences other than starting with a db restore between RestoreRun and Normal mode?

Any insight into this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstood the documentation. It doesn't say to use RestoreRun on production. It says that you should use it during development when your db is already in production.

Comment: Ahh... you're right. And it all suddenly makes sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I've found a few clues that confirms *what* it does, but I still don't understand *why*. I found this [dialog](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/chucknorrisframework/U4C8ZSf_pFM) between a user and the author of RoundhousE:

> **Q:** Is RestoreRun the same as Normal except it performs a restore from
>   backup first?
>
> **A:** Yes, and it does not run items in the runAfterCreate folder either. It
>   includes the /restore /restorefrompath=VALUE
>   /restorecustomoptions=VALUE /restoretimeout=VALUE items. 
>   https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse/wiki/ConfigurationOptions

Answer (score 0):

these must be new modes as I don't see them in rh.exe options with the version i have.

"\shared\MSBuild\Roundhouse\rh.exe" -w /restoretimeout 36000 /cs=%server.connectionstring% /f=%sql.files.directory% /vf=%version.file% /vx=%version.xpath% /r=%repository.path% /env=%environment%

This is equivalent to the Normal mode.

For production your going want something like above.
Any new scripts you do not want run in production need to have ENV.%environment%.sql  so that when the environment is set to production those scripts are not executed.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like these new modes are a bit of a mystery. Thanks for sharing your configuration.

Comment: Any reason you set restoretimeout without any of the other restore parameters? I was under the impression that this value only had an effect if you had RoundhousE restore a database backup.

Comment: It was probably just a typo, but to exclude a script from production, you need to set the filename to a different value than your production environment name, i.e. if your %environment% variable is "PROD" for production, then any files you don't want to run in production should not contain "PROD", but some other value, like "DEV" (e.g. ENV.DEV.myscriptname.sql)

Comment: It could be reworded differently, however, you've captured my  intentions. Another Tip: You could also make use of the properties in the configuration object inside the ENV.DEV.TEST.sql by using a simple token replacment system that rh provides {{EnvironmentName}} and {{DatabaseName}}